# How to generate PDF Files based on a HTML+CSS+jQuery page containt

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, pdf-generation

I'm trying into my ASP.NET MVC 4 web-app based on C#, to allow the end-user to download a pdf-file, which it will be generated from an HTML+CSS+JQuery coded page. In fact, this page contains HTML text fields which allows end-users to enter data and then to generate statistics will be displayed in the same web-page to deal this I have used highcharts, a jQuery library which displayes statistics based on data inputs.

The problem here, that I have tried to implement `Rotativa` (doesn't work with ASP.NET MVC 4), `ITextSharp`, all what they offer is the conversion of a pure HTML file into PDF, and, doesn't take the fact of the jQuery charts.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't take the fact of .. "? Chart are not rendered at all, or just partially? The problem may be that Highcharts are dynamic charts and are rendered in SVG. Check if Rotativa support SVG. If charts are rendered only partially (like title, legend), then disable all animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try jsPDF. it is an open-source library for generating PDF documents using nothing but Javascript.
link for [JsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)